# How to enter this complex string in helm template?

Tags: formatting, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have this problematic string I want to use in helm template.
Eventually, I'd like my yml file to contain:

```
pattern.console: "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p [My App,%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]) %clr(22988){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %-0.-10000m%n%wEx"
```

I tried using string functions like `quote`, `print` and `cat`, but I can't find the way to represent this string in the gotmpl file. For example, the following fails because of the `%` sign.

```
appConfig:
  application.yaml:
    test: {{ cat "\"%clr" }}
```

If I try putting the string as is:

```
appConfig:
  application.yaml:
    test: "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p [Data Maintenance,%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]) %clr(22988){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %-0.-10000m%n%wEx"
    test2: "111"
```

I get the string shorter, with a line-break in the middle, and other values disappear from the output (`test2`):

```
data:
  application.yaml: |
    test: '%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p [Data Maintenance,%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}])
      %clr(22988){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that string contains the Go templating markers `{{ ... }}` so you should be able to include it as-is.  How are you providing the value and how are you emitting it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dave! I've added more info to the question.
Unfortunately it doesn't work to put the string as is

Comment: What template code produces that output given that input?

Comment: helmfile version v0.149.0